# In MySQL, if I have a known but large amount of values, should I add them as columns or create a new linked table?

Tags: php, mysql

In trying to design something in MySQL, I came up with the issue where I had to store an array of the same size for each user (which would be about 20 or so). I did some research about using a new table and linking the two using foreign keys. However, I wasn't sure which one would be more "clean" or scalable for larger numbers of users.

Strategy 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS members (
username    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
#email, password, etc.
user_id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
data1       INT
data2       INT
...
data20      INT
)
```

Strategy 2, which involves creating a new table and using a foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
user_id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
data1       INT
...
FOREIGN KEY data_fk(user_id)
REFERENCES members(user_id)
ON UPDATE SET NULL
ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I realize that premature optimization might not be the best idea, but I want a recommendation for which strategy is better, or if there is another one that I can use.

Some other helpful information might be at what point I should consider other changes or how I can generally improve the consistency of the data.

**Edit:** To make this question more clear, the "data" would be statistics for a browser game. It will likely be pulled on every page reload. Each user will have exactly one datum for every column. I am trying to determine whether strategy 1 will work for a large number of users and whether or not it is secure/good coding practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Is every user supposed to have all the parameters?  Do you anticipate adding more parameters in the future?

Comment: @PM 77-1 I guess that is a pretty important factor, and I think I do foresee possibly adding a few parameters in the future. To answer the other question, yes, each user will have all the parameters.

Comment: Then keep one table.

Comment: @PM 77-1 Thanks for the help! I'll leave this question up for now to see if there are any other responses, though.

Comment: That depends on what you are going to do with the data. Without more details (requirements) this question is either "too brad" or "opinion based".

Comment: If the data is reliant ENTIRELY on the primary key (user_id) and that alone, then normally it should be part of the same table.  If the data is reliant on anything else (for example an effective date) then it should be split.  It may help if you gave your fields more meaningful names as this can also be confusing in the future.

Comment: Yeah, the fields were just filler names in the question, I'll change that in the actual table. The data is supposed to be linked to the specific user, and thus the `user_id`. There wouldn't be any problems with this data being in the same table as the email and password, right?